# expr string matching-mixed number and chars?

Tags: regex, bash

When I typed

```
$ expr match "can't find" 'c'
$ 1
```

Then I typed

```
$ expr match "234can't find" 'c'
$ 0
```

I can't figure out why?

Answer (score 3):

The `man` page for the version of `expr` isn't very clear:

```
STRING : REGEXP
          anchored pattern match of REGEXP in STRING

match STRING REGEXP
          same as STRING : REGEXP
```

What, exactly, does "anchored" mean? The BSD version clears things up:

> The regular expression is anchored to the
>                beginning of  the string with an implicit ``^''.

So `expr match "234can't find" 'c'` is identical to `expr match "234can't find" '^c'`, and since your string doesn't *begin* with a `c`, the match fails.

---

Since `bash` supports regular expression matching natively, you can forgo the `expr` command in favor of

```
[[ "234can't find" =~ c ]]
```